# Lock MVC ActionResult after specific date?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to block access to my `[HTTPGET]` after specific date.

My WebApplication based on ASP.NET MVC 4.

ActionResult i need to lock from 20 december is simple httpget.

Any idea?

Comment: How about checking the current date and returning an http error?

Comment: That is the simplest way, may be there is some specific method or action filter that can deal with it.

Comment: Of course you can implement a custom action filter, afaik such a filter is not available in ASP.NET MVC by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the most basic form:

```
public ActionResult Get()
{
     if(DateTime.Now >= new DateTime(2013,12,20)) // I haven't check this constructor call
     {
         return RedirectPermanent("/someurlname");
     }

    return View();
}
```

If you need to do this in more places and to stay DRY I would write an ActionFilter.